# How to get the action type from redux toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I created a `Slice` using `createSlice` from redux toolkit and exported my action such as:

```
export const { myAction } = slice.actions;
```

I am trying to create a middleware to catch some action type:

```
import myAction from './reducers/mySlice'

const MyMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === myAction.type) {   //this doesn't work, myAction is a function
    doSomething(action.payload);
  }
   return next(action);
};
```

I was wondering if it was possible to get the action type as a constant from the slice I created?

Comment: Thank you very much for `action.type` tip. I didn't even know that we can call `.type` on action to get an actual type!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your import statement is wrong.  You're doing a named export (`export {myAction}`), but a default import (`import myAction`).

Change it to `import {myAction} from './reducers/mySlice'`, and that middleware could should work.

Action creators also have [a `.match()` function attached](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#actioncreatormatch) that you can use:

```js
if(myAction.match(action)) {
  // logic here
}
```